# Safari extension : How to provide update for my safari extension?

Tags: ios, safari, extension-methods, safari-extension, browser-addons

I developed a safari extension say v1.0 and ready to be uploaded in the safari extensions gallery. A next version say v1.2 will be shipped in the same gallery in another few months. Now, my question is,

When I upload v1.2 , will the existing version get automatic updates?

Do I have to specify any special key - value terms in my info.plist file for either of the versions?

Can anyone explain how this update process of safari extension gallery works?

P.S : I am uploading only in the safari Extension gallery, not in my own webserver. So I get my extensions signed.